# Is placing <script>stuff</script> in page text edit window bad form?

Tags: jquery, javascript

After noodling around on the web to figure out how to add additional jquery features to a WP page, a question follows.
After 'enqueue-ing' a js/jquery file in the theme's function.php file and then adding some js/jquery (see example below) directly onto a page via the edit text feature in the control panel to call the extended jquery feature in the enqueue-ed file, the desired feature works on the page. Is it considered bad practice to add js/jquery scripts in their tags directly to a page?

Example:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $("#someID").somePlugin(); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is typically considered bad form to do that. The only reason you might do that is if the script you are including will be used on the page you are editing and ONLY that page.

Comment: Ahhh..... this resonates. So for adding modified jquery features to ONE page, this is minimally acceptable but perhaps not best practice. But if one want the modified jquery features to traverse one's entire site, follow other procedures like Jack above. Do I have your point, Eric.

Comment: Yep. You've got it. @stumpjumper64

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add any sort of code directly inside the text editor. It will most likely be stripped, and even if not, it's not a good idea to permit a code being run directly from a text editor output.

Instead, use `wp_add_inline_script()`. Put this piece of code inside your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
$my_plugin = '
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $("#someID").somePlugin(); 
    });';
wp_add_inline_script('my-script' , $my_plugin);
```

This will add inline scripts after your `my-script` enqueued file. You have to have a JS file enqueued, and attach this inline script to it, which means you have to change `my-script` to whatever the ID of your enqueued script file is.

Comment: to be clear on your points. **1** Only use html in the page text edit window? **2** In my case, the added script (see above) in the page text edit window does not appear to be stripped since the new feature/plugin is functional when viewing the page outside of the editing mode. **3** I'll have to experiment with the procedure you proposed, Jack. Is that standard practice or a working hack? Thanks for the input.

Comment: It **should** be stripped. If it's not, then probably some plugin/function is messing around with some hooks. Adding a code directly inside the editor is a security issue. The solution i provided is the standard way to include an inline script. You can find more information [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/).

Comment: Also if you want to filter your code only to be printed on some specific pages or post types, you can add a conditional to the code. If so, add the details to the question and i will update the answer.